# When does a function take an open interval into an open interval?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we consider a function $f(x)$ defined from an open interval say $(a,b)$ to some set $T$. When would the set $T$ be an open interval?

Comment: Functions that verify the condiction "the image of an open set is itelf an open set" are called *open functions*. You may verify that homeomorphisms are open functions, but there are several functions which are open without being homeomorphisms.

Comment: When would that open set be an open interval?

Comment: If you're using $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology (I guess you are, since it's a real analisys question ;) ), then open sets are the unions of open intervals and open intervals are open sets.

Comment: Certainly when $f$ is continuous it maps intervals to intervals (so continuous and open implies maps open intervals to open intervals).

Comment: I very much doubt that one can find a nontrivial necessary and sufficient condition for the problem as stated.

Answer (score 2):

To give some sense to how little can be said without any further restrictions on the function, consider this: There exists a map $f\colon(0,1)\to(0,1)$ which maps every nonempty open subinterval of $(0,1)$ onto $(0,1)$.

I don't know if such a function can be given explicitly, but here is an existence proof ultimately relying on the axiom of choice:

Write $x\sim y$ if $x-y$ is rational. Then $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $(0,1)$. Write $E$ for the set of equivalence classes. Then the cardinality of $E$ equals that of $(0,1)$, because each equivalence class is countable. In particular there is an onto map $F\colon E\to(0,1)$. Define $$f(x)=F([x])$$ where $[x]$ is the equivalence class of $x$.

Now given any $y\in(0,1)$ and $0<a<b<1$ there is some $x\in(0,1)$ with $F([x])=y$. We can certainly find some $x'\in(a,b)$ with $x'\sim x$, so that $f(x')=F([x'])=F([x])=y$. Hence $f$ maps $(a,b)$ onto $(0,1)$ as claimed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. Wasn't looking for an explicit example though.

Answer (score 2):

The set $T$ would be an open interval if the function is also injective, that is, supposing that T is a subset of R and $f$ is continuous.